# CORS in SPring Security with custom SecurityFilter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I face problems with using my custom SecurityFIlter which process JWT from Frontend and CORS

I have my custom Security FIlter which includes in SecurityFilterChain.
This Filter processes each Http request and looks for JWT (created by our app). If JWT is found, the Filter verify it and if It's not valid -> returns error(400) response.
But the problem with CORS, because when the FIlter returns repsonse it doesn't comprise of Access-Origin Header because request and response were not processed by CORS.
I Configured WebMvcConfigurer

```
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
```

But I don't want to implicity set these Headers to the Response in the FIlter.
How can I do it?
The Filter ->

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        var authorization = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (authorization != null && !authorization.isBlank() && authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            var jwt = authorization.replace("Bearer ", "");

            if (jwt.isBlank()) {
                sendResponse(response, HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, Map.of("jwt-error", "Invalid JWT Token in Bearer Header"));
            } else {
                try {
                    UserDetails userDetails = jwtUtil.validateTokenAndRetrieveClaim(jwt);

                    createAuthentication(userDetails);

                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                } catch (JWTVerificationException ex) {
                    sendResponse(response, HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, Map.of("jwt-error", "Invalid JWT Token in Bearer Header"));
                }
            }
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: _This Filter processes each Http request and looks for JWT_. There is your problem. The CORS filter must come before any auth filter, since CORS preflight requests are not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to configure cors() in HttpSecurity. In such way, there is CorsFilter which process all requests before my custom Filter and set all the necessary header.